# Facebook: Gender-specific dummy profile pictures via graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to retrieve gender-specific dummy profile pictures via the graph API if possible. By trial and error, I found a URL that retrieves the genderless picture: https://graph.facebook.com/picture?type=square. So I'm hoping male and female might be available too.

Comment: Download them to your server.  Problem solved ;)

Comment: I'd rather not get on the wrong side of facebook's T&Cs and copyright.

Comment: Even if Facebook never noticed or cared, those images are copyrighted and are Facebook's IP, if you decide to use them anyway, so be it, but don't ignore the fact that they're not public images

Comment: @Igy - are there any references for this?

Comment: @SteveTaylor - what about creating your own similar images?

Comment: Why would there be? Facebook made the images, so they hold the copyright and they're not automatically free to use unless specifically released under a royalty free licence, which I don't believe they have been

Comment: @Igy: Agreed, which is why I want to get them the legit way or not at all. If need be, I'll serve up my own.

Comment: @SteveTaylor surely when retrieving a user's photo, if they haven't specified one, you'll get one of those images back by default? (i.e no need to cache the image on your side)

Comment: @Igy - good to know.  note taken.

Comment: @Igy yes, but I'm catering for the case where a service provider (gender is important) is on my site but there isn't an associated facebook profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating two test users under your app, one of each sex.

Then point to their generic pictures

http://graph.facebook.com/TEST_USER_ID/picture?type=square,

That way if at any point Facebook changes their pictures, you automatically get those changes.  :)

Comment: as long as they don't get closed for being fake users this is a great solution.

Comment: @DMCS it's a novel approach and thanks, but I tend to agree with Lix. Your solution isn't quite in the spirit of the question, which is to do this the legit way, as discussed in the question's comments.

Comment: What is not legit about it?   You already have a Facebook app, so utilize the test users that come with it. As long as you are using those two images in your app, I highly doubt facebook would have any issue with it.  if you're using them outside of your app, then hell no!  Don't use it.

Comment: @DMCS sorry, being the graph API n00b that I am, I didn't realize it was possible to actually create test users. Not knowing that, I thought you meant creating fake user accounts. Apologies and thanks. :)